# Will bitter cucumbers ruin gazpacho?

Tags: cucumbers, gazpacho

I plan to make gazpacho in a blender. I'll be using the following ingredients, all blended together:

3 medium-large tomatoes
1/2 cup cucumber pieces
1/4 cup onion
1/2 cup bell peppers
1 Tbsp. Red wine vinegar
A few ice cubes
1 drop Tabasco sauce
Salt and pepper

The problem is that the cucumbers we have on hand are somewhat bitter. Will using these make the gazpacho also taste too bitter?

Comment: Did you peal the cumbers?

Comment: No. Perhaps I should though.

Comment: You absolutely should if they are bitter, most of the bitterness is in the peels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of turning into a recipe question so it may get closed.

Most recipes call for peeled and seeded.  See how it tastes peeled and seeded.  You have a other strong flavors so unless unless it is very bitter it is probably OK.  Maybe cut back on the cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

*Gazpacho* is a classic chilled summer soup that has transcended its Spanish origins and found its way onto the menus of a multitude of Spanish and non-Spanish restaurants throughout Europe and beyond. Cooling cucumber is one of a number of staple ingredients but using bitter-tasting cucumbers will likely upset the established taste parameters in a classic version of this delicious cold soup.

Answer (score 0):

My gazpacho recipe makes 6 cups. I used different cucumbers, and suspect they caused bitterness. I added 2 teaspoons balsamic glaze (balsamic vinegar slowly reduced at a simmer by half volume) and this was perfect!